# Как передать данные из Custom layout в activity (не в MainActivity)?

Tags: android

не знаю как передать данные на другой activity(который не является MainActivity) тут я передаю количество в корзину. Корзина находится в layout.dialog_lay1. пробовал передать Референсом и Интентом. буду рад идеям. Все присходит так  есть **активити1** в нем 6 кнопок каждый открывает новый активити, и каждом свои фрагменты ввиде диалогового окна

```
public class Asma1 extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public int TvPlus_Minus = 0;
private TextView mValueTv;
private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
public TextView adet_asma;
public static String input1;
public ImageButton on_siparis1;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private static final String PREF_VAL = "PREF_VAL";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getDialog();
    View mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.asma1, null);
    adet_asma = mview.findViewById(R.id.text_value);

     mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    //updatedValue(getValue());

    mview.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlus).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        TvPlus_Minus++;
        adet_asma.setText(String.valueOf(TvPlus_Minus));
        //updatedValue(getValue() + 1);
    });

    mview.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonMinus).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        TvPlus_Minus--;
        adet_asma.setText(String.valueOf(TvPlus_Minus));
        //updatedValue(getValue() - 1);
    });

    mview.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonclose1).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        dismiss();  //close dialog
    });

    mview.findViewById(R.id.on_siparis).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        input1 = adet_asma.getText().toString();
        if (!input1.equals("0")) {
            //mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
            ed.putString("PREF_VAL", "PREF_VAL");
            ed.apply();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "заказ добавлен в список", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            dismiss();  //close dialog

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "o", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    return mview;
```

тут я принимаю значение

```
public String va;
public  TextView adet_asma;
public SharedPreferences mPrefs;
//public static final String PREF_VAL = "PREF_VAL";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_lay1);
    close_dialog = findViewById(R.id.close_dialog);
    close_dialog.setOnClickListener(this);

    
    adet_asma = findViewById(R.id.text_siparis);
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    va = mPrefs.getString("PREF_VAL","PREF_VAL");
    adet_asma.setText(va);



   //adet_asma.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("input" + va));

  //  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  //  if (extras != null) {
  //     String value = extras.getString("input");
  //      adet_asma.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("input" + value));
  //   }
```

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста больше информации, не очень понятна логика требуемого поведения и итоговый результат которого вы пытаетесь добиться

Comment: в программе можно заказать блюду.   в mview.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlus).setOnClickListener(v -> {++}  mview.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlus).setOnClickListener(v -> {++}  добовляю количество                а тут mview.findViewById(R.id.on_siparis).setOnClickListener(v -> {} пытаюсь сохранить значение и передать  количество.

Comment: сохраненное дожно быть в корзине ввиде список без нажатие кнопок. как открываю корзину я пищу имя, номер, адрес и в конче список продуктов.  нажатием кнопки отправляю все данные поставщику ввиде sms-ки

Comment: есть у кого идеи?